# API Update ebay inventory in regular interval

Tags: php

I want to update the bulk inventory of product on  ebay. There is any Api available for that, I will run the cron job from another website and update the inventory in  30 minutes interval.

Is there  any API available for that?

I have searched on **“Ebay developer program”** but haven’t got any solution.

Comment: All of the API's are documented (just search for `ebay api`). If the docs aren't there, you might want to contact eBay.

Comment: Right now on Ebay there is no chat option available. If I will get any help then its good for me.

Comment: StackOverflow isn't the place to demand ASAP help. No SLA here. Just volunteers.

Comment: @DavidMakogon yes, sorry for that. I have checked on ebay but haven't got any solution.

Comment: https://go.developer.ebay.com/

Answer (score 2):

The eBay API provides several operations for managing listings on eBay. Most of these are available in the [Trading service](https://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/index.html).

For listing items to eBay the two main operations are [AddItem](https://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/AddItem.html) and [AddFixedPrice](https://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/AddFixedPriceItem.html). For updating listings once they are live there is [ReviseItem](https://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/ReviseItem.html) and [ReviseFixedPriceItem](https://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/ReviseFixedPriceItem.html).

The eBay documentation has a lot of information on [adding](https://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/guides/ebayfeatures/Development/Inventory-Adding.html#AddingInventory) and [managing](https://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/guides/ebayfeatures/Development/Listings-Managing.html#ManagingInventory) inventory.

Just be aware that listing to eBay via the API is not easy. In addition to working with the API you need to know how selling on eBay works in general.

Comment: Should i use new sell API or old trading api for adding a new product and update the product.   The problem with new sell API is that it wants user consent to get access token and i want to use ebay api without user consent for cron job.